# Include badge rank in Badges table on data explorer

Tags: feature-request, badges, data-explorer, tag-badges

I've discovered that there's no way to differentiate between a bronze, silver, and gold tag badge. For example, take this query (run on SO):

```
SELECT * FROM Badges WHERE Name = 'javascript'
```

It returns:

```
Id      UserId  Name       Date          
------- ------- ---------- ------------- 
273683  16417   javascript 2009-04-01 18:40:06
378136  5445    javascript 2009-07-10 15:03:24
571563  18936   javascript 2009-12-04 01:47:14
664312  34397   javascript 2010-02-10 20:15:53
666137  187606  javascript 2010-02-11 02:05:05
759018  182668  javascript 2010-04-03 23:50:08
845349  96100   javascript 2010-06-02 15:01:59
847409  145190  javascript 2010-01-31 06:10:51
1032904 45433   javascript 2010-08-16 10:23:44
1037159 25330   javascript 2010-01-29 19:32:19
...
```

How am I supposed to tell if it's a bronze, silver, or gold tag badge?

Therefore, I request that a.) a `Rank` column be added or b.) tag badge names be changed to `javascript-bronze`, `javascript-silver`, and `javascript-gold`.

Comment: By inner joining on `Users`, then `Posts`, then `PostVotes`... come to think of it it would be easier :-).

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards But then it would return three gold tag badges for someone who has earned all three. :P

Comment: Only if you assumed too much @Doorknob; a gold badge, by definition, means that a silver and bronze exist, etc.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards ...which is definitely *waaay* too complicated. :D

Comment: It's part of my job @Doorknob; so, it's good to know that it's not too simple :-). But, it's really not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* determine gold/silver/bronze tag badges with the current data: [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/68615/gold-silver-and-bronze-tag-badges) is a query Tim Stone put together and I edited.