# Add a BadgeTypeId to the Badges table on SEDE

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, badges, data-explorer

When trying to derive badge statistics on [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) it would be helpful if there was an identifier (say `BadgeTypeId`) that would mark the badge as being

1. Bronze badge
2. Silver badge
3. Gold badge
4. Bronze tag badge
5. Silver tag badge
6. Gold tag badge

Motivation: A while back (not reproducible anymore) we had an {epic} tag on [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com). With the [Badge table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244) having only a `Name` field to identify it, it wasn't easy to discern between the regular [silver epic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/epic) and the bronze/silver/gold {epic} tag badge.

I can see that, in the long run, some sites might be more affected than others where there could exist an overlap between the tag names and badge names. [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) springs to mind where TV shows or movies might have titles similar to some badges.

[Can we expose class for badges in Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148147/168244) requests the addition of badge *class*. This post requests something more: class and *type* (tag/regular).

Comment: Also: [Include badge rank in Badges table on data explorer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221242/include-badge-rank-in-badges-table-on-data-explorer)

Comment: @hichris123: Not an exact duplicate, as I'm interested not only in the class, but also the type (regular/tag).

Comment: Realistically, you need *both* of these, the type *and* class, in order to be sure you're identifying the badge correctly (you're calling both of these type, the other request thinks they're both class, but really they're two (occasionally orthogonal) attributes).